# Ultimate Psionics - Claws of the Beast

Tags: pathfinder-1e, psionics

I'm having a hard time understanding claws of the beast.  Does it stack with bite of the wolf?  To be precise, do you get 2 claw attacks and 1 bite attack per round by having both of these psionic abilities active?  Also, I don't understand how much damage claws of the beast does. I created a chart to help simplify this.. is the chart correct?  This is for a medium creature - don't go into size increases.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Regarding damage, your chart is correct. The base damage of the claw attacks increases, just like having a larger weapon.

You can manifest both *claws of the beast* and *bite of the wolf* at the same time. This will give you 2 claws and 1 bite **natural weapons.** On a normal character, you could make three attacks as a full attack, each at your highest attack bonus (all three natural weapons are "primary").

*However*, the claw attacks from *claws of the beast* comes with extra restrictions on top of that of normal claws. From the final paragraph:

> If you attack with a manufactured weapon or another primary natural attack, you can’t make any claw attacks in that round.

If you use this strictly as-written, then you cannot use the power's claw attacks in the same round as making an attack with a manufactured weapon or other primary attacks (such as bite).

This sentence conflicts with the previous paragraph, which details how the claw attacks can be used as secondary weapons alongside a manufactured weapon. I believe that this is *likely* the result of poor editing. In D&D 3.5, the power [did not have the additional text detailing this](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/powers/clawsoftheBeast.htm); it was added in by Dreamscarred Press during their conversion to Pathfinder.

Given this inconsistency, my recommendation is to houserule away the restriction at the end of *claws of the beast*, allowing the claws to work like normal natural weapons and be combined properly with other weapons.

Comment: "You could attack with your claws first and then follow with a bite attack" - I disagree with this. The quoted text for claws of the beast does not mention before or after. Order does not matter. So, if you attack with the claws of the beast first, you won't be able to use a bite as a primary after, and vice versa.

Comment: If order didn't matter, it wouldn't be worded like that. It's pretty clearly stated as "if X (you attack with another weapon), then Y (you can't make claw attacks)."

Comment: Though, thanks to the self-contradictory nature of the power's wording in general, there's no way someone makes it out of this without a GM call.

Comment: If you attack with the claw, and then attack with a weapon, you have broken the restriction. Therefore, you cannot attack with claw, then weapon. If you attack with weapon, then claw, you have also broken the restriction as written. Order doesn't matter.

Comment: As I read it, order doesn't matter really. But you could use  a manufactured weapon and still make a secondary bite attack. Keep in mind that the SRD material is from *unleashed*, Ultimate Psionics has updated some powers (and several class mechanics), so it's worth checking there too.

Comment: I believe that this phrase is in error: *If you attack with a manufactured weapon or another primary natural attack, you can’t make any claw attacks in that round.* As this clearly affects rules and abilities way outside the context of this power.

Comment: It could be read that way. Sadly, I don't think there's a good way to find out what the developers of DSP's psionics intended though (I've asked them about a fair few things in UltPsi, but it's been long enough that they have no idea), so we only have conjecture on that. Edited the answer in any case, to remove commentary about attack ordering.

Comment: Guys, if you disagree with an answer then post your own and let the votes decide